# Using Javascript or Jquery to populate Hidden Field Value

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently using a script to populate a hidden field from Select Options

Basically, the user selects a Membership Level and a Price (from Mysql) is applied to the Hidden Field (PaymentAmount).

The current script seems to be hit and miss (that is, works) dependent on browser. I may have to refresh the page several times for it to work. I have positioned the script in different places on the page - header, footer, and now directly under the SELECT field.

```
<input name="PaymentAmount" id="PaymentAmount" type="hidden" value="" />

<select id="MembershipType" required aria-required="true" name="MembershipType" class="form-control">
<option selected="selected">--Select--</option>
<option value="Level-One">Level One</option>
<option value="Level-Two">Level Two</option>
<option value="level-Three">Level Three</option>
</select>


<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $('#MembershipType').change(function() {
        var price = $('#MembershipType').val();
         switch(price)
         {
         case 'Level-One': 
         $('[name=PaymentAmount]').val(<?php echo $row['Level-One']; ?>.toFixed(2));
         break;
         case 'Level-Two': 
         $('[name=PaymentAmount]').val(<?php echo $row['Level-Two']; ?>.toFixed(2));
         break;
         case 'Level-Three': 
         $('[name=PaymentAmount]').val(<?php echo $row['Level-Three']; ?>.toFixed(2));
         break;
         }
      });
    });
</script>
```

Advice to produce a more effective and reliable script to achieve this (using either jquery or javascript)?

Comment: You should provide more specifics. Under which browser does this not work? Under which browser DOES it work? Does it provide any error message? What about the script doesn't work?

Comment: it's a strange one.. It works in all browsers I've tried.  But I have to force refresh the page several times in say Safari for Mac before the value is applied to the hidden field. When it doesn't transfer, no errors are shown, value of hidden field is just VALUE="".

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Toji

Based on your answer, have started with

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#MembershipType").click(function(){
    $("#PaymentAmount").val("<?php echo $row_Pricing['Level-One']; ?>");
             });
    });
</script>
```

And now concentrating on using below example and adapting

```
<script>
  $( "select#MembershipType" ).change(function() {
     var str = "";
     $( "select option:selected" ).each(function() {
     str += $( this ).text() + " ";
    });
  $( "div" ).text( str );
    })
    .trigger( "change" );
</script>
```

But am not skilled enough to take this further..

Answer (score 0):

Perserving... Down to

```
<script>
    $(document).ready( function ()
        {
        $('#MembershipType').change(function()
        {
        var option = $(this).find('option:selected').val();

        switch(option)
            {
            case 'Level-One': 
            $('[name=PaymentAmount]').val(<?php echo $row['Level-One']; ?>.toFixed(2));
            break;
            case 'Level-Two': 
            $('[name=PaymentAmount]').val(<?php echo $row['Level-Two']; ?>.toFixed(2));
            break;
            case 'Level-Three': 
            $('[name=PaymentAmount]').val(<?php echo $row['Level-Three']; ?>.toFixed(2));
            break;
            }
        });
});
</script>
```

Seems to work!!

Answer (score -1):

Why you cannot assign Id to the hidden field and then use jquery selector

Comment: Thx Toji - Looked at this but was unsure how to use (I'm still trying to get my head around jquery)